# Nested quantifiers - Discrete Maths exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm a little confused about the following exercise:

Let S(x)   be "x is a student", F(x)   be "x is a faculty member" and A(x,y) be "x has asked y a question"
The domain is "all people associated with your school".
Use quantifiers to express each of these statements

The predicate is: Some student has not asked any faculty member a
question

I've found this solution on the web
$$
\exists x \forall y {\big(}( F{\small(x)}\land S{\small(y)}) \implies \lnot A{\small(x,y)} {\big)}
$$
I'd have translated this predicate in the following way:
$$
\exists x \forall y {\big(}F{\small(x)}\land (S{\small(y)}\implies\lnot A {\small(x,y)}){\big)}
$$
Do you think that first solution is correct?

Comment: no, It wasn't intentional, thanks for noticing It. I should translate those predicates by using quantifiers

Comment: In your first and second statement (before $F(x)$) is a bracket which isn't closed again.

Comment: ah, sorry, It's my first question

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" you quoted from the web is nonsense. Your own solution would be right if you just interchanged $F$ and $S$. As it stands, it says there is a faculty member who hasn't asked any student a question.